# SQL Insert missing records into 3rd table from 2 others having data that is paired in the 3rd

Tags: sql, join, insert, multiple-tables

I have three tables, condensing here to pertinent columns (modified from original post 8/20/14):

1. CODES            (WAGECODE, DESCRIPTION),
2. EMP     (EMPCODE,                        FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
3. EMPWAGE (EMPCODE, WAGECODE, DESCRIPTION, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)

There are 5 unique CODES.WAGECODE records with a description for each.
There are 5 unique EMP.EMPCODE with First and Last names

The EMPWAGE table should have 5 records for each of the 5 EMP.EMPCODE (25 records)

My schema on SQLFiddle includes 16 of the needed records, with 9 more needed.
I have the following code which isolates the needed data for the 9 records:

```
SELECT E.EMPCODE, C.WAGECODE, C.DESCRIPTION, E.FIRSTNAME, E.LASTNAME
FROM
(EMP E CROSS JOIN CODES C)
    LEFT JOIN EMPWAGE EW ON E.EMPCODE = EW.EMPCODE AND C.WAGECODE = EW.WAGECODE
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
       FROM EMPWAGE EW
       WHERE
           E.EMPCODE = EW.EMPCODE AND C.WAGECODE = EW.WAGECODE
      )
```

I am however stuck on the process to insert this data (9 records) using SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cfe7/7 and I would appreciate assistance.

In adding the following to the first line of the above, my SQLFiddle remains unchanged after run

```
INSERT INTO EMPWAGE (EMPCODE, WAGECODE, DESCRIPTION, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
```

The Schema used for SQLFiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cfe7/7:

```
CREATE TABLE CODES (WAGECODE varchar(5) NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION varchar(30) NULL);

Insert into CODES values ('001', 'RegHours');
Insert into CODES values ('003', 'Holiday');
Insert into CODES values ('008', 'Sick');
Insert into CODES values ('010', 'PCH');
Insert into CODES values ('397', 'Comp');

CREATE TABLE EMP (EMPCODE varchar(11) NOT NULL, FIRSTNAME varchar(15) NULL,
LASTNAME varchar(15) NULL);

Insert into EMP values ('BretV', 'Bret', 'Vick');
Insert into EMP values ('CarlS', 'Carl', 'Shaw');
Insert into EMP values ('MaryC', 'Mary', 'Comb');
Insert into EMP values ('RickK', 'Rick', 'Kite');
Insert into EMP values ('TamiB', 'Tami', 'Ball');


CREATE TABLE EMPWAGE (EMPCODE varchar(11) NOT NULL, WAGECODE varchar(7) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION varchar(30) NULL, FIRSTNAME varchar(15) NULL, LASTNAME varchar(15) NULL);

Insert into EMPWAGE values ('BretV', '001', 'RegHours', 'Bret', 'Vick');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('BretV', '003', 'Holiday',  'Bret', 'Vick');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('BretV', '008', 'Sick',     'Bret', 'Vick');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('BretV', '010', 'PCH',      'Bret', 'Vick');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('BretV', '397', 'Comp',     'Bret', 'Vick');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('CarlS', '001', 'RegHours', 'Carl', 'Shaw');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('CarlS', '010', 'PCH',      'Carl', 'Shaw');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('MaryC', '001', 'RegHours', 'Mary', 'Comb');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('MaryC', '003', 'Holiday',  'Mary', 'Comb');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('MaryC', '397', 'Comp',     'Mary', 'Comb');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('RickK', '001', 'RegHours', 'Rick', 'Kite');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('RickK', '008', 'Sick',     'Rick', 'Kite');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('TamiB', '001', 'RegHours', 'Tami', 'Ball');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('TamiB', '003', 'Holiday',  'Tami', 'Ball');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('TamiB', '008', 'Sick',     'Tami', 'Ball');
Insert into EMPWAGE values ('TamiB', '010', 'PCH',      'Tami', 'Ball');
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Please post a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: For `MySQL`, with a 'fix once', defining a proper UNIQUE key & just running an `INSERT IGNORE` query for the whole bunch would be quite alright in my book. Not if this has to run on a regular basis though.

Comment: Actually, the query you listed from ErikE *IS* for three tables and should work just fine for you, assuming that you understand SQL.

Comment: I have created an SQLFiddler as requested, hopeful I am correct that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e15ab/1 will allow access.  Please feel free to spoon feed me as this is my first time on this site.  DARP

Comment: This DB currently SQLExpress 2008 (John Conde).  This would be a one time run to fix, with similar to run for each new employee added(Wrikken). I will continue work with ErikE query to see if I can get it to do what I need (RBarryYoung).  Not yet solved.